# How far back can a native Florentine understand their written mother tongue?

Tags: history

Language changes with time, we all know. What was once a common phrase becomes dated and a new word is substituted.  Can a 21st Century Florentine understand what was written during the 19th, 18th, 17th or 16th Centuries?
Can they read the works of Dante Alighieri, Boccaccio, Niccolò Machiavelli or Alessandro Manzoni in their originals?  How far back can they understand their language?

EDIT - Clarifying -  If a 21st Century native Florentine speaker can easily read Boccaccio, without notes or aids, then it's got to be an earlier date. If they can't, then the limit has to be some time after Boccaccio. I'm not asking for a specific year, but there have been so many writers during the past 500 years, that two of them must mark the limit between easily understanding and not understanding without notes or any help. The question is not whether the average Florentine speaker can or cannot understand "The Divine Comedy".  It's **when did the written Florentine language change that it cannot be immediately understood nowadays?**

Comment: Related: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8527/can-native-italian-speakers-read-the-divine-comedy

Comment: @Hachi  My question is "how far back can the written language be easily understood by the average 21st Century Florentine, without any aid.  Can Alesandro Manzoni be easily understood?  If so, can a piece of lieterature written in the 18th Century be read and understood?  And so on.

Comment: Not sure how this differs from the related question linked by Hachi. Could you clarify? “Can a 21st Century Florentine understand what was written in the 18th or 16th Centuries? Can they read the works of Dante Alighieri...?” ≈ “Can native Italian speakers read The Divine Comedy?” (remember that Standard Italian is basically Florentine dialect).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can native Italian speakers read The Divine Comedy?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8527/can-native-italian-speakers-read-the-divine-comedy)

Comment: @DaG If you can easily read Boccacio, without notes or aids, then it's got to be an earlier writer. If you can't, then it has to be some time after Boccacio. I'm not asking for a specific year, but there have been so many local writers during the past 500 years, and two of them must mark the limit between easily understanding and not understanding. The question is not whether the average Florentine speaker can or cannot understand "The Divine Comedy". –

Comment: The accepted answer to that earlier question informs us that Dante is mostly readable to present-day Italians. Dante is the first great author writing in Italian; hence, you are actually asking about authors preceding Dante, and 1) there are not a whole lot of them; 2) their texts are often preserved in a later Tuscanised form (for instance, this is true for most of the early Sicilian poetry), so for them most of what was said for Dante still holds.

Comment: Oh, and if you actually mean just authors writing in Florentine, there is more or less just a single generation of them before Dante.

Comment: @DaG   I mean any reading material: literature, astronomy, physics, medicine, history, law, newspapers, governmental issues, etc.  any written material, not only literature. Of course that requires some research,

Comment: @Centaurus The earlier material is typically written in Latin (with the exception of the poorly preserved Sicilian poetry and some religious literature). In fact Dante wrote a lengthy treatise (in Latin!) to justify his "unusual" choice of language.

Comment: Non-fiction material was mostly written in Latin up to Galileo's time.

Comment: The most ancient known commercial letter in Florentine is from 1291 (the same years as Dante's _Vita Nova_), and it is perfectly understandable to a contemporary Italian: https://wps.pearsoned.it/wps/media/objects/13367/13687937/01_testi_commentati_01.pdf

Comment: @Centaurus I'll add a short survey of the older texts this evening, but there's not much to be said.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be interested in the oldest Italian text readable by a native speaker. Unfortunately the problem is that there just aren't many old Italian texts, especially from Tuscany. Here I'll list the main ones I could find (my source is Migliorini's *Storia della lingua italiana*), limiting to texts coming from Tuscany and neighboring areas, together with some comments about how easy or hard I found them to read.

The first document arguably in vulgar Tuscan I could find is the *postilla Amiatina*. It is just a short note at the end of a donation certificate in favor of a monastery on mount Amiata (dated 1087) that reads

> Ista cartula est de caput coctu
> ille adiuvet de illu rebottu
> qui mal consiliu li mise in corpu

To be honest this looks a lot more like vulgarized Latin than Vulgar. Migliorini conjectures it is an attempt to "latinize" the following words

> Esta carta è de Capucottu
> e ll'aiuti dellu' rebottu
> che mal consigliu i mise in corpu

Its interpretations is in any case rather obscure, because of the uncertain meaning of the word *rebottu*. To be honest I'm in doubt that one should even count this, and I'm including it only for completeness.

Next comes the [*Ritmo Laurenziano*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salv%27a_lo_vescovo_senato). This is a longer text, you can find it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20070703082610/http://www.fh-augsburg.de/%7Eharsch/italica/Cronologia/secolo12/Laurenziano/lau_ritm.html). It dates to the mid twelwth century and it's not easy to read (mainly for the lacunae). It begins as

> Salva lo vescovo senato,    lo mellior c'umque sia na[to],
> [. . .] ora fue sagrato    tutt'allumma 'l cericato.
> Né Fisolaco né Cato    non fue sì ringratïato,
> e 'l pap' ha·ll [. . .-ato]    per suo drudo plu privato.

There are a few words that are definitely archaic and might require even a moderately educated speaker to open a dictionary (*umque* "never", *drudo* "friend"), and the spelling is definitely non-standard (*cericato*?). I would say that this is borderline readable. I suspect that without the lacunae and with a little more context it would be easier to guess the meaning of the unfamiliar words. It also uses several words in very "Latin-like" form, presumably because it was intended for the court of the bishop, where Latin would have been very common.

The next document is the [*Ritmo lucchese*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ritmo_lucchese). This is a short poem describing a fight inserted in the middle of a history (in Latin). It is dated around 1213. It is too long to transcribe here (the complete text can be found [here](https://archive.org/details/ritmovolgarelucc00debauoft/page/6/mode/2up)), but let me copy a portion here:

> Stiano a mente, ben lo dico:
> che a Lucca sempre sia schifato
> e a Lucca sempre sia odiato;
> aver di Lucca non i sia dato;
> tolto i sia quel che a pilliato,
> ka di Lucca l'à 'nvolato:
> tutto fu dello sacrato!

In my opinion this text, while definitely archaic, is already perfectly comprehensible to an educated Italian speaker.

After this the next available documents in Tuscan are the literary works of the *Dolce stil novo* school. These are slightly more archaic than Dante's *Commedia*, but not significantly so and I would argue are already perfectly readable by any educated Italian speaker. Arguably we should lump with them the Tuscanized transcriptions of the poetry of the Sicilian school, which are either contemporary or shortly before them.

Comment: Reading Dante without comments/footnotes is trickier than you make it sound, in my view. I can parse most sentences, and get the general meaning, but there are enough archaic terms that it is difficult to get a complete understanding. Much less so for the other authors (also because they do not write in metrical rhymed lines).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni We agree that Dante is harder than Boccaccio, but I think I [already said](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8527/can-native-italian-speakers-read-the-divine-comedy/8528#8528) my piece about reading Dante (TL;DR requires some guidance, especially the parts that delve deep into Scholastic theology, but the language is mostly understandable), and I stand by it. I read the whole Comedy on my own, in middle school, and one gets used quite quickly to the language

Comment: Note: I completely rewrote the answer to focus on the pre-Dante period, as requested in the question.

Comment: I appreciate your effort to answer my question.  Somehow, the information I need is not clear to me.  Although you claim not to be a Florentine, you say you can **easily** read B and D.  From your answer I gather you're very skilled in Italian history and Italian Language (this is not a compliment, but a pertinent observation). and I wonder whether the average Florentine would feel the same and agree that they can easily read B and D.  Should they understand those authors easily, then the answer has to be some earlier writings.

Comment: @Centaurus I can speak only for myself, but I expect any educated Italian speaker to easily read B and D. They're basic high school curriculum! It's true that some Italian speakers have difficulties with them, that's why I'm using the weasel word "educated" (e.g. I don't expect someone like my grandfather with only a primary school degree to be able to read them easily, although maybe with difficulty). The reason is, as I wrote in the first version of the answer, that the Italian taught in schools since 1861 was actually *modeled* on D & B, so it's not surprising that people can read them!

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It helped.

Comment: I.e. the Italian taught in schools in 1861 was not based on some contemporary spoken Italian (which didn't exist) or contemporary spoken Florentine (Manzoni's proposal, rejected as impractical), but rather on the *written* language of the educated minority that was kept as close as possible to thirteenth century Florentine.